# What are the names of session ids for Python and Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, session

I want to know the names of session identifiers for Python and Ruby, for example, the names of session identifier for J2EE is JSESSIONID, for PHP is PHPSESSID.

Can you help me please?

Comment: In Ruby, it's `session`, which is a hash. So to use it, it need a key and a value, e.g. `session[:user_id] = user.id` where `user` is a `User` object.

Comment: in python its also `session` and it is usually imported from whatever framework you are using ...

Comment: Hi, I think they aren't, for example, if I capture the http traffic of a ruby applicaation request, would I see something like this `session: <value of session>`? I want to know the name of session identifier for python and ruby when it appears in a http request.

Comment: I think `request.session_options[:id]` is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, I have the asnwer of my question:

I captured the HTTP traffic of some python and ruby on rails applications, the most common sessions ids for each language are the following:

-Python:

> sessionid

-Ruby on Rails: The format of session id is: `

> _{Name of application}_session

For example, for my "ExampleRoRApp" application, the sessiond id is:

> _ExampleRoRApp_session

Thanks for your comments.